# xlwings VBA function settings edit

Tags: python, windows, xlwings

I would like to use xlwings wit the OPTIMIZED_CONNECTION set to TRUE. **I would like to modify the setting but somehow cannot find where to do it**. I change the _xlwings.conf sheet name in my workbook but this seems to have no effect. Also I cannot find these settings in VBA as I think I am supposed to under what is called "Functions settings in VBA module" in the xlwings documentation. I tried to re-import the VBA module but cannot find xlwings.bas on my computer.(only xlwings.xlam that I cannot access in VBA)

I am using the 0.11.4 version of xlwings.

Sorry for this boring question and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

- The add-in replaces the need for the settings in VBA in newer versions.
- One can debug the xlam module using "xlwings" as a password.
- This enabled me to realize that the OPTIMIZED_CONNECTION parameter is now set through "USE UDF SERVER" keyword in the xlwings.conf sheet (which does work)